# Multiple maps using a single dataset based on shiny template 063

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I would like to modify the following shiny template but run in to prolems:

http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html

I would like to have two leaflet map tabs but I am not able to understand how to do so, because there are two inputs and I don't know where they come from. Those inputs are input$map_bounds and input$goto.

If I have two maps I should have two map_bounds. How do I know how the second one will be named?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. I determined that the leaflet() function (or maybe the renderLeaflet I'm not sure) generates its inputs in the following manner:

```
#In ui.R
....
leafletOutput(outputId = "foo",...)
....
```

will give you "inputs$foo_bounds", "inputs$foo_zoom" and "inputs$foo_click". To test that you can create two leaflet outputs and integrate the following code in the server side:

```
#server.R
....

output$map <- renderLeaflet({
print(names(input))
leaflet() %>%
addTiles(
urlTemplate = "//{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/jcheng.map-   5ebohr46/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
attribution = 'Maps by <a href="http://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>') %>%
setView(lng = 2.49, lat = 47, zoom = 6)})

output$map2 <- renderLeaflet({
print(names(input))
leaflet() %>%
addTiles(
urlTemplate = "//{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/jcheng.map-5ebohr46/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
attribution = 'Maps by <a href="http://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>') %>%
setView(lng = 10, lat = 47, zoom = 6)})
....
```